# Height-based, vertically-aligned, percentage-based img using display: table/table-cell

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm creating a variant of the well-known media object which meets the following criteria:

- Container element has an explicit height set
- Height of all children should be percentage-based
- Image element should be able to be vertically-aligned

I'm using the age-old `display: table`/`table-cell` approach as such:

```
<div class="o-media">
  <div class="o-media__img">
    <!-- begin picture component -->
    <div class="c-picture">
      <div class="c-picture__container">
        <picture class="c-picture__el">
          <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://www.topoutshoes.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/_/1/_11_1_7.jpg" class="c-picture__source">
          <img src="http://shopshoeguru.com/sites/default/files/image/shoeguru-banner-red.png" class="c-picture__img _o-media__image--overview-01" alt="Overview 1 photo">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end picture component -->
  </div>

  <div class="o-media__body">
    <!-- some copy and such -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.o-media {
  height: 550px;
}

  .o-media__body {
    height: 50%;
  }

  .o-media__img {
    height: 50%;
  }

  ._o-media__image--overview-01 {
    /* want to be able to set this using percentage! */
    height: 200px;
  }

.c-picture {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

  .c-picture__container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .c-picture__el {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .c-picture__source {
    display: none;
  }

  .c-picture__img {
    display: block;
  }
```

Here's a jsfiddle of this code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/v9gf3c9a/

The issue, as noted by my comment within the CSS, is that I have to explicitly set the height of the `img`, as it won't respect percentage-based heights, due to the use of `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. If I use regular-old `display` values, such as `block` and `inline-block`, a percentage on the `img` works fine.

Is there any way to achieve this so that I can use a percentage on the `img`, but still use `vertical-align` via `display: table`/`table-cell`?

Comment: not sure i understand ... but picture should be figure :) https://jsfiddle.net/v9gf3c9a/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus - How would the `<source>` element work then? `<source>` needs to work with `<picture>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.o-media {
  height: 550px;
}

  .o-media__body {
    height: 50%;
  }

  .o-media__img {
    height: 50%;
  }

  ._o-media__image--overview-01 {
    /* want to be able to set this using percentage! */
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }

.c-picture {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

  .c-picture__container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .c-picture__el {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
  }

  .c-picture__source {
    display: none;
  }

  .c-picture__img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Alternatively you could use flexbox, with `align-items: center;` on the flex container.

Comment: Rad! Just to simplify a bit, the `_o-media__image--overview-01` could be made `height: 100%`, and then the `c-picture__el` could be used to control the percentage height. Also, `c-picture__el` may need `width: 100%` to consume proper metrics. Otherwise, looks great! Thanks! I hadn't even considered messing with positioning.

Comment: Yes, my initial intent was to keep the img 100%, and adjust the height of its immediate container, I just messed it up. Fixed it.